# How do I get a list of rows in a two column matrix that contain NA OR value < 0?

Tags: r

I have a two(for testing) column array(cols) of 10 rows.  E.g.
cols

```
       V243  V247
1   693   761
2  -733   791
3   665  -756
4    NA   892
5   821    NA
6   752   819
7  1092 -1137
8    NA   943
9   675   720
10  600   645
```

I wish to get a one column 10 row vector with a T or F if ANY column contains an NA on that row, and another one column 10 row vector with a T or F if ANY column contains a value < 0 on that row.  I want to get:

```
na_column neg_column
F            F
F            T
F            T
T            F
T            F
F            F
F            T
T            F
F            F
F            F
```

which(is.na(cols)) returns 4, 8, 15.
It returns the list of indices of the two column array as if it were flattened into a one row with the columns concatenated.  I want it to look at each row and if ANY column of that row contains an NA, then return that row number.  I should get 4, 5, 8.

Similarly for the negative value, I need 2, 3, 7.
I am at a loss as to how to do this.  It seems like it should be easy in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this option:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,NA,-3), v2=c(4,5,NA))
rowSums(!is.na(df)) < ncol(df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

as.logical(rowSums(df < 0, na.rm=TRUE))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Data:

```
  v1 v2
1  1  4
2 NA  5
3 -3 NA
```

### Demo

Comment: Nice. I totally forgot the `na.rm` argument in rowSums. Also my initial way for the first part was ```is.na(do.call(`+`, df))```

Comment: why not just `as.logical(rowSums(is.na(df)))` in the first case ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Because in the first case it was already spitting out logicals?  You don't really need `as.logical` in the second case, either, if you just plan on using the results somewhere, since 0/1 pretty much behaves the same as `FALSE/TRUE` in most areas of R.

Comment: I get why you didn't need `as.logical` in your case as you used a comparison but the negation + comparison with `ncol(df)` is unnecessary as far as I understand.

Comment: To give OP the expected output I suggest `df$na_column  <- substr(as.logical(rowSums(is.na(df))),1,1)` and `df$neg_column <- substr(as.logical(rowSums(df < 0, na.rm=TRUE)),1,1)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I think you should just post your own answer, rather than starting a conversation here around code which appears to  be working.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$na_column <- is.na(rowSums(df))
df$neg_column <- apply(df, 1, function(r) any(r < 0, na.rm = T))

df
#    V243  V247 na_column neg_column
# 1   693   761     FALSE      FALSE
# 2  -733   791     FALSE       TRUE
# 3   665  -756     FALSE       TRUE
# 4    NA   892      TRUE      FALSE
# 5   821    NA      TRUE      FALSE
# 6   752   819     FALSE      FALSE
# 7  1092 -1137     FALSE       TRUE
# 8    NA   943      TRUE      FALSE
# 9   675   720     FALSE      FALSE
# 10  600   645     FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: Another way to get the first column is `na_column <- apply(dat, 1, anyNA)`.

Answer (score 0):

`any` and `all` are function in `R` that do, what you want. Thus it is easy in R

```
expl <- read.table(text="
          693   761
         -733   791
          665  -756
           NA   892
          821    NA
          752   819
         1092 -1137
           NA   943
          675   720
          600   645")

apply(expl, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
apply(expl, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: This not produces the desired result for the negative values. `neg_column`

Comment: True. It is simple to expand that, but as I see now, C.Braun has answered 5 Minutes before me with basically the same approach and (s)he already did the negative values part as well. So I upvoted her/his answer instead of editing mine.

Comment: `transform(df, na_col=apply(df, 1, anyNA), neg_col=apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x<0, na.rm=TRUE)))` or `transform(df, na_col=apply(df, 1, anyNA), neg_col=apply(df<0, 1, any, na.rm=TRUE))`